# Scala - Expression of type Unit doesn't conform to expected type DataFrame

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I wrote a method reading files from S3. If a file exists it returns a DataFrame, otherwise it throws an exception. I'm getting a compiler error: `Expression of type Unit doesn't conform to expected type DataFrame`.

As far as I understand this is caused by the logic of throwing an exception in the else branch. 
The only option that I see for now is to return a default value instead of throwing an exception. But the method must return a DataFrame. Maybe I should use an Option in some way?

I'll be grateful for any suggestions on how to achieve returning a DataFrame in this case.

```
import java.nio.file.{Paths, Files}

def loadMetricsData(dataPath: String, metricsData: String): DataFrame = {
  if (Files.exists(Paths.get(s"$dataPath/$metricsData.json"))) {
    val metricsDataDF: DataFrame =
      spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json(s"$dataPath/$metricsData.json")

    metricsDataDF
  } else throw new IllegalArgumentException("File doesn't exist")
}
```

UPD: There was a typo in the if block not returning metricsDataDF, it contained just an assignment.

Comment: Yes, that's the whole idea of using a functional programming language like Scala. Better avoid throwing exceptions and wrap your call in a Monad. In your case, it could be the Option Monad!

Comment: Throw and exception has type `Nothing` not `Unit`. Your problem is that **assign to a val** _(which is what you are doing in the right branch)_ does has return type `Unit`. Juts remove the `val metricsDataDF: DataFrame = ` and just leave the rest of the code.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez uh, the assignment was my typo. It is actually returning the `metricsDataDF`

Comment: @samba your code as it is in your question, should compile and work as expected _(I just compiled it)_. Either, your real code is different _(and thus, this question does not reproduce the error)_ or the problem was already fixed and you didn't noticed. - BTW, if the error comes from IntelliJ or any other IDE, please confirm the error is real by using a compiler instead of an IDE before opening a question.

Comment: @samba, Yes the current code that is in your question should be just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have returned an object of type "Unit" instead of "DataFrame" in your method. In your "if" statement, you have assigned a variable with the result of a method call. In Scala, assignment statement returns a Unit.

You can either return the result variable like below:

```
def loadMetricsData1(spark: SparkSession, dataPath: String, metricsData: String): DataFrame = {
  val res = if(Files.exists(Paths.get(s"$dataPath/$metricsData.json"))) {
    spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json(s"$dataPath/$metricsData.json")
  } else throw new IllegalArgumentException("File doesn't exist")
  println("output is: " + res)
  res
}
```

Or simply, you can avoid assigning the result to a variable like this:

```
import java.nio.file.{Paths, Files}
def loadMetricsData(dataPath: String, metricsData: String): DataFrame = {
  if(Files.exists(Paths.get(s"$dataPath/$metricsData.json"))) {
    spark.read.option("multiline", "true")
        .json(s"$dataPath/$metricsData.json")
  } else throw new IllegalArgumentException("File doesn't exist")
}
```

Comment: I've updated  the post with regards to my typo. It is actually returning the `metricsDataDF` in the if block